# List elements don't float in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I've seen this issue around the web a ridiculous amount of times, but all so far have been based around `<li><a>Test</a></li>` etc.

What I'm trying to do, simply is:

```
<ul>
<li class="title">Test</li>
<li>Test2</li> ** These should float together on the same line **
<li class="title clear">Test</li> ** New Line **
<li>Test2</li>
</ul>
```

This works fine for me on everything but IE6, in which puts the list elements on seperate lines.

A jsFiddle of this can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/pjWdg/

Please view on IE6 to notice the error, every other browser works fine.

I've tried:

```
ul, ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.clear {
   clear: both;
}

li.title {
   width: 200px;
}

ul > li {
    float: left;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
ul > li {
    display: inline;
}
```

All to no success. Can anyone shed some light into how I can make this work? Thank you!

** UPDATE **

Now, after removing the > in the list style, I've got:

http://jsfiddle.net/pjWdg/1/

You can still see this is wrong, with Test2 appearing next to Test3?

Comment: @RohitAzad - Not helpful man. Sometimes it's not your call. If a client wants it supported then you've got to do it.

Comment: Yep, a lot of government agencies still use it I'm afraid - thus I have to cater for it unfortunately!

Comment: Yep, give me a few mins.

Comment: Updated my question with the fiddle.

Comment: Works fine in my browser, breaks up after 2nd list item???

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pjWdg/1/ - you can see "Test2" is next to "Test3", when it shouldn't be. Are you definitely using IE6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try These Changes in your style sheet.

```
ul, ul li {
list-style: none;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

.clear {
clear: both; 
}

li.title {
 width: 200px;
  float:left;

}
```

Comment: This is it! This works! I can't even spot the difference other than the float: left on the title, but wohoo! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

IE6 doesn't support the child selector `>`

Use `ul li` to target your li's instead.

Comment: Close, but look at the updates jsFiddle - Test2 and Test3 appear together. Do you know why this is? http://jsfiddle.net/pjWdg/1/

Comment: Also, IE6 doesn't support multiple classes on an element. Put a `clear: left` on `.title` and remove the clear class entirely

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't work, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/pjWdg/4/. I appreciate your time on this, I really do. I just want IE6 to play nicely.